# elegant way to defer val resolution

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have a `val`:

```
val something = System.nanoTime
```

that then goes through a series of method calls:

```
foo(something) {
  bar(something, 2) { etc }
}
```

I'd like to defer `val` resolution until a very last method that actually does something with it. I'm aware of scala's `lazy` modifier, but it seems that passing `something` as a parameter automatically resolves it's value, regardless if the variable is being used or not inside that method.

My (somewhat ugly) solution so far is:

```
val something = () => System.nanoTime
```

Although this works, it involves changing all the method signatures, in this case from `Long` to `() => Long`. I guess there might be a more elegant way of solving it, what do you guys think?

Comment: `val something = () => System.nanoTime` wouldn't it be the same as `def something = System.nanoTime` without the to change signatures?

Comment: no, since: `something != something`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to do this without changing the signatures, however you should use `x: => Long` instead of `x: () => Long`. The first is a so called `by name parameter`. A by name parameter will be evaluated, **every time** you call it. So in total it would look like:

```
def foo(x: => Long) = {
  x + 12 // x will be evaluated here
}

lazy val x = 12L
foo(x)
```

Comment: The part with by-name-parameters is formulated improperly. They are executed each time they are called, in your description they look like being the same as a `lazy val`.

Comment: Cf https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-240 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809313/scalas-lazy-arguments-how-do-they-work