# Writing a function that returns => T

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a simple converter that turns a `java.util.Function` into a `scala.Function1`:

```
def toScalaProducer[T](f: JavaFunction0[T]) : => T  = => f()
```

Here is another variant that works well:

```
def toScalaFunction[T](f: JavaFunction0[T]) : () => T =
  () => f.apply()
```

The problem is that I want to pass the converted function into an existing Scala API, but [that API](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/af1fbc7af36a755117fd2b4dca8bd3fac825363d/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Future.scala#L89) only accepts arguments of type `=> T`, not of type `() => T`.

Is there a way to write the `toScalaProducer` function?

Comment: Are you sure this doesn't work? That is not a type, that is called lazy evaluation, that is, the thing you pass in as `a` is evaluated only when needed in the body of the method and not before, in short, you need to pass in `A` as type, and `() => T` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`() => T` is the type for a function that takes no arguments and returns something of type `T`

`=> T` is the type for a value `T` that is lazily evaluated.  For instance:

```
def myFunc(t: => Int): Unit = {
   // Do something with t
}

myFunc(reallyExpensiveFunctionProducingAnInt())
```

Here, `reallyExpensiveFunctionProducingAnInt` could take a long time to run, but will only be executed if the value `t` is used in `myFunc`.  If you just use type `Int` instead of `=> Int` it will have been called before `myFunc` is entered.

Have a look here for more information: [Scala's lazy arguments: How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809313/scalas-lazy-arguments-how-do-they-work)

So if your `toScalaProducer` function simply executed the Java function and had a return value of `T`, it should work fine with the API.  It will only be executed when needed, so in many ways will behave like passing a function.