# Is there a reason to use std::conjunction/std::disjunction instead of a fold expression over "&&"/"||"?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Is there any specific cases you cannot correctly do with `std::conjunction`/`std::disjunction` and not using the more "fundamental" (i.e. language feature instead of library feature) fold expression over `&&`/`||`?

Example:

```
// func is enabled if all Ts... have the same type
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...> >
func(T, Ts...) {
 // TODO something to show
}
```

vs

```
// func is enabled if all Ts... have the same type
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same<T, Ts> &&...)>
func(T, Ts...) {
 // TODO something to show
}
```

The version using a fold expression is more brief and generally more readable (although opinions might differ on that). So I don't see why it was added to the library together with fold expressions.

Comment: "In-house" implementations of `conjunction` and `disjunction` are still useful in projects where C++17 fold expressions are not available (for whatever reason).

Comment: Reason **NOT** to use it: you end up with a ridiculous number of instantiations of the `std::conjunction`/`disjunction` template (one for every combination passed), **and** each one takes quadratic time to evaluate (first one passes N - 1 args in recursion, second one passes N - 2 args, etc...). This is slow to compile...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`std::conjunction` short-circuits `::value` instantiation, while the fold expression doesn't. This means that, given:

```
template <typename T> 
struct valid_except_void : std::false_type { };

template <> 
struct valid_except_void<void> { };
```

The following will compile:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto test = std::conjunction_v<valid_except_void<Ts>...>;

constexpr auto inst = test<int, void>;
```

But the following won't:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto test = (valid_except_void<Ts>::value && ...);

constexpr auto inst = test<int, void>;
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/V99KHr)

---

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction):

> Conjunction is short-circuiting: if there is a template type argument `Bi` with `bool(Bi::value) == false`, then instantiating `conjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for `j > i`.

Comment: Minior nitpick: [Fold expressions do short circuit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111274/are-fold-expressions-subject-to-short-circuiting/50115876).  It's they just need to instantiate all members of the pack before they check the values while `std::conjunction` only instantiate members as needed. still +1

Comment: What causes a template to not be instantiated? Is the function special in that way or do all parameter packs that are not used directly kept uninstantiated?

Comment: @user975989: it's not the template, it's the `::value` access that is short-circuited. This is done by the implementation of  `conjunction`

Comment: Is there any point to using `conjunction/disjunction` with standard type traits that **always** have `::value` defined? Or am I wrong about this assumption?

Comment: @r3musn0x to avoid unnecessary instantiation

Comment: Conjunction is short-circuiting: if there is a template type argument Bi with `bool(Bi::value) == false`, then instantiating `conjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for j > i.