# Short circuiting in fold expressions

Tags: c++, c++17, lazy-evaluation, short-circuiting, fold-expression

This is a self triggered question based on a self-answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126792/5825294).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048635/5825294) seems a pretty convincing explanation of why short-circuiting of logical operators is available in [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold), and of the fact that wrapping a fold expression in a function with a variadic argument *seems* to be non short-circuting (in fact, the answer explains, it's the function call which triggers the evaluation of all arguments, before the short-circuit can take place inside the function body).

However, the following code seems to me, proves that (at least when the arguments in a fold expression are 2) the short-circuiting doesn't happen:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <optional>

constexpr auto all_r = [](auto const& ... ps){
    return [&ps...](auto const& x){
        return (ps(x) && ...);
    };
};

constexpr auto all_l = [](auto const& ... ps){
    return [&ps...](auto const& x){
        return (... && ps(x));
    };
};

constexpr auto has_value = [](std::optional<int> o){
    return o.has_value();
};
constexpr auto has_positive = [](std::optional<int> o){
    assert(o.has_value());
    return o.value() > 0;
};

int main() {
    assert(!(has_value(std::optional<int>{}) && has_positive(std::optional<int>{})));
    //assert(!(has_positive(std::optional<int>{}) && has_value(std::optional<int>{}))); // expectedly fails at run-time


    assert(!all_r(has_value, has_positive)(std::optional<int>{}));
    assert(!all_l(has_value, has_positive)(std::optional<int>{})); // I expected this to fail at run-time
    //assert(!all_r(has_positive, has_value)(std::optional<int>{}));
    //assert(!all_l(has_positive, has_value)(std::optional<int>{})); // I expected this to succeed at run-time
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `ps(x) && ...` or `... && ps(x)` changes anything to the associativity of the `&&` operation. So why expect different behaviours?

Comment: @prog-fh the two forms are exactly to impose the associativity in one direction or the other.

Comment: But what does this change with only two arguments? (starting from three I see the difference) I used the bad term indeed: not associativity but order of evaluation.

Comment: @prog-fh I think I've understood my mistake. I was erroneously expecting that the order of evaluation was being mirrored in the two forms just like the associativity is mirrored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`... && ps(x)` with four predicates `a, b, c, d` expands to

```
( ( a(x) && b(x) ) && c(x) ) && d(x)
```

which leads to this order of evaluation: `a b c d`

`ps(x) && ...` expands to

```
a(x) && ( b(x) && ( c(x) && d(x) ) )
```

which leads to the same order of evaluation: `a b c d`

This does not change anything about short-circuiting; as soon as one is false, the evaluation stops.

Answer (score 0):

Start with what `Pack && ...` means.

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) has a pretty readable description.

`Pack && ...` becomes `Pack1 && (Pack2 && (Pack3 && Pack4)))`
`... && Pack` becomes `(((Pack1 && Pack2) && Pack3) && Pack4`

When evaluating `&&` we evaluate left to right at the top of the parse tree.

For the `Pack&&...` case, this top level `&&` is `Pack1` then the and operator, then `(Pack2 && (Pack3 && Pack4))`.  `&&` evaluates the left side first, and if false it stops.

For the `...&&Pack` case, the top level `&&` is way on the right.  Its left hand is `(((Pack1 && Pack2) && Pack3)` and its right hand is `Pack4`.

But to find out if the left hand is true, we keep on applying that rule.  And the very first term we end up evaluating is... `Pack1`.  Which if it is false, we don't bother evaluating the rest.

While the shape of the tree is different, it doesn't matter as much as one might think.

```
  +
 / \
A   +
   / \
  B   C
```

and

```
      +
     / \
    +   C
   / \
  A   B
```

when doing an in order traversal visit the nodes in the same order, and left / right fold just switch which of these two expression trees is generated.

There are cases where the left/right fold matters, but `&&` on things evaluating to `bool` isn't one of them.